# How to change server time on mt4

Tags: mt4

After Googling it I haven’t found how to change the time showed in my MetaTrader4 terminal, when the local time is different from the time of the server of the broker.

Is there a parameter in some of the .ini configuration files that do the thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such `.ini` option.

Server simply ***dictates*** the time-labelling of the Fx-Market `QUOTE`-s.

In the recent `"New"-MQL4.56789` there has appeared another new function that indicates, whether the Server-side has already went on/off a DST-offset or not.

> ```
> int  TimeDaylightSavings();
> ```
>
> **`Return Value`**
>
> Returns correction for daylight saving time in seconds, if the switch to summer time has been made. It depends on the time settings of your computer.
>
> If switch to winter (standard) time has been made, it returns **`0`**.